# NSButton subclass still runs mouse event methods even when enabled is NO

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

The `setEnabled:` method is not working in my subclass of `NSButton` in which I have overridden `mouse{down,drag,up}` and `rightMouse{down,drag,up}`. I feel the enabling/disabling of the button should be outside these functions -- the button should not be receiving mouse events in the first place when it is disabled.

Do I have to make a check explicitly when I am overriding these functions?

Comment: Why shouldn't it receive mouse events when it is disable? Just don't do anything when the button is disabled by checking with conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you do need to do your own check.

As explained in [Apple's writeup on Cocoa Event Architechture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW11), the window containing your button is sending `mouseDown:` (or whichever other method is appropriate) to your button in response to recieving an event. In order for the window to decide not to send the message, it would have to first determine that the button is an `NSControl` subclass (`enabled` being a property of `NSControl`, but not `NSView`) and then check that `enabled` flag. That is beyond the window's area of responsibility. A control being enabled isn't part of the event dispatch system the way first responder status is.

As an interesting piece of insight, if you take a look at [GNUStep's `-[NSControl mouseDown:]` implementation](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-gui/blob/master/Source/NSControl.m#L877), they do indeed check `[self isEnabled]` before handling the event.